# Symlinks or Alias within a LAMPP setup running Joomla

Tags: apache, xampp, mod-alias

Sorry for the imprecise wording of this question however I have really hit a wall here.

I have installed XAMPP/LAMPP on a machine running Debian. I then installed joomla on the installation of LAMPP. Everything is running correctly. I am now trying to add either a symlink or an Alias to the httpd.conf file. Which httpd.conf file should I edit?

I think I have somewhat correctly added something to the relevant files becuase the access log returns this:

```
GET /Archived/test.html HTTP/1.1" 403 1043
```

Obviously i'm getting 403 errors when I try to connect to the directory. I have tried applying permissions to everywhere I could think of. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful, thanks!

Comment: You should edit httpd-vhosts.conf to create a virtual subdomain. Newer versions of Apache may need "Require all granted" in <Directory>